# Java Applet in JAR File

Tags: java, jar, applet

I have created a java applet (.class file) and made a .jar with it and digitally signed the .jar file. Now I need to run the .jar as an applet in firefox. What do I put in the html code to run the .jar file as an applet? I tried   and it doesn't work, it tries to get a .class file, how do I load and run my applet as a .jar file using the applet tag in Internet Explorer and Firefox? I searched on the internet and could not find an answer.

Comment: Note that any data in the applet tag parameters is not signed, and so may be replaced by a malicious third party. So don't trust it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

should work

```
<applet code=TicTacToe.class 
        archive="TicTacToe.jar"
        width=120 height=120>
</applet>
```

(The class has your main() I assume, the jar is the entire thing)

Comment: +1 Sorry to jump in like that, but I thought I saw a different link.

Comment: Thanks, that works, it fixed my problem. I needed to put archive into the applet tag, now it works and my applet loads successfully.

Answer (score 5):

What doesn't work? Any errors? Does it show up at least?

The HTML is as simple as:

```
<applet code="class_that_extends_Applet.class" archive="your_signed.jar">
    <param name="param1" value="value1">
    <param name="param2" value="value2">
</applet>
```