# Can I sign Java Class Files

Tags: java, code-signing

I have a website that was professionally built about 8 years ago and generally works absolutely fine. It uses a Java applet to chart stuff and now Oracle is requiring all Java code to be signed. I have 2 problems:

1. The company that built the site went bust in the credit crisis
2. There is no Java file on the site it seems calls are made to the class files directly.

Site uses ASP.net and was built in Visual Studio. Question.. can the java class files be signed or is it only possible to sign a jar file?

thanks for your help! PS/ I'm a non-expert in Java but I built the original site before it was rebuilt 8 years ago, so you could say I'm a sort of relatively capable amateur!

Comment: As I read [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html), Oracle is requiring that applets (that run on the web browser) be signed, or else the user will be annoyed by "are you sure?" popups.  Haven't mucked with applets for about 10 years, but my understanding is that they ship in jars, and that's sort of what the article implies.  Note that this all applies to the *applet* that runs *on the web browser*.  What runs on the server is not affected.

Comment: Well, it's kind of got beyond "are you sure?" to an implication that "this is pretty unadvisable" and they're saying that soon signatures will be required. I'm tempted to wonder whether Oracle's solution to all the exploits in Java is to externalize the problem and say everyone has to have everything signed. Easy for them..

Answer (score 1):

You can package your classes in a jar file and sign the jar. Depending on how you are loading your applet in the browser, you may need to modify the HTML tag a little bit.

For more info on creating a jar file:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

For more info on signing a jar: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html

For more info on loading an applet from a jar
[Java Applet in JAR File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982935/java-applet-in-jar-file)

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I tried setting up a JAR file, but the site seems not to be set up to use one so I need to sign the class files directly if possible. Thing is, I don't know if it is possible..

Comment: You can sign any file. I don't think signing a class will solve your problem. Also, I am not sure if signing a class directly is going to corrupt the file!. Don't you have access to update the site to use Jar file?