# how to run java jar applet in google chrome?

Tags: java, applet

I want to run a java j2me application in google chrome as an applet. I tried using microemulator, but failed. Please could you tell me how to do that ?

My setup is the following : windows7, 32 bit, java jre version 8, java plugin 11.something, Google chrome version-36.       Actually i want to run java .jar j2me application( opera-mod-4.2) in google chrome. i run java .jar application in my pc using microemulator. It run ok. It has a option  make for web., When i clicked it an appled html file and two jar file is created in a folder, when i tri to run this html file in google chrome. It becomes a white blank screen. but not run the application.

Comment: Can you show us some code? How are you embedding the applet in your HTML page? What have you tried so far and which problems you had exactly? Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982935/java-applet-in-jar-file?rq=1 already?

Comment: AFAIK Chrome has the Java plugin disabled by default and you will need to manually enable it.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
 <head>
  <title>MicroEmulator</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <applet code="org.microemu.applet.Main"
    width="1366" height="662"
    archive="microemu-javase-applet.jar,opera-mini-4-2.jar">
   <param name="midlet" value="Browser">
   <param name="device" value="org/microemu/device/resizable/device.xml">
  </applet>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: Actually when i run the applet a white blank screen aries in google chrome(Itri other browser but the same problem occer.I want to run java j2me .jar application in google chrome, Please Tell me.Step by step.

Answer (score 8):

1. Enter `about:plugins` in the search field.
2. In the Plug-ins list, look for Java and check whether Java is enabled (if the Disable link appears, Java is already enabled)
3. Click on the Enable link (if available)
4. (Optional) Check the Always allowed box to stop additional Chrome warnings when running Java content

Got it from: http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml

If it doesn't help, tell us the error message and try another browser to give us a clue.

Comment: about:plugins redirects to chrome:plugins which has disappeared in chrome canary