# How to make a jar file run as a java applet in a browser

Tags: browser, jar

As the title of my question, I would like to run a `.jar` file as an `applet` in a browser. How can I do that? Is there any possible solution? i have to edit this because someone was stupid enough to read this as a java applet in a jar file when I am trying to achieve the exact opposite thing, that's like saying a potato chip is a chipped potato

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Applet in JAR File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982935/java-applet-in-jar-file)

Comment: no,it is the exact opposite,can you read english? i want to run a jar file as if it is an applet

Comment: an applet is - at minimum - a Java class extending java.applet.Applet or javax.swing.JApplet packaged in a JAR file. a JAR file can contain anything from related classed that make up a library to executable cmdline or standalone programs with a user interface (Swing/AWT/SWT). so you should point out what your JAR file - that you want to run as an applet - does... if it's a Swing application it's possible to refactor it so that this JAR can be executed as a stdalone client from cmdline or by doubleclicking the JAR-file and as well run this application as an applet in your browser.

Comment: for example, how would I get Minecraft to work,just as an example

Comment: because that is gibberish to me, as it is not formatted well, and lacks some basic grammar. it looks like a run-on sentence at first glance